# How do I convert a Keynote file to a high resolution PSD?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format, keynote

I mocked up several marketing materials for my team in Keynote, and I'd like to convert them into high res files (preferably PSDs or JPGs) to upload to a printing site (like Vistaprint). I've tried to convert to PDF and JPG directly from Keynote, but the files come out pixelated and at a much lower resolution when uploaded to the printing site.

I'm hoping I can solve the pixelation upon upload by converting my Keynote files to PSDs (if at all possible).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most like a result of working with sources that are too small in raw pixel dimensions.

If you have a slide for a 1080p resolution screen, then you have an image that is 1920x1080 pixels. The optimal print size for this would be *about* 6x3 inches: the image dots (px) divided by the typical for-print resolution of 300dpi. If you have a mockup that takes up less than the screen and you want it 11 x 8.5 or something, then now you are stretching after export and this is Bad For Quality.

The way DTP software (inDesign, QuarkXPress, Scribus etc.) works with this is by "linking" the images and then displaying a screen-only low-pixel-count version for us to evaluate placement etc. When the file is exported to PDF or sent to a RIP for plates, the software refers to the data in the linked file rather than the placeholder image.

In Keynote/Powerpoint etc. the image is usually imported and placed, **and destructively downsampled** to the low-res placeholder. When you export, you are now exporting data from the low-res copy. If you export one-to-one that is fine, but if you now want to print it, well, you then have to re-add pixels and the quality suffers.

I don't use Keynote, but a quick google shows me people speaking about, for instance, disabling downsampling and/or avoiding downsampling bugs by placing a PDF.

Additionally, if you have type, you want to export as PDF and look to ensure that **font embedding** is enabled. Type is usually rendered above 300dpi. In Ye Olden Days, black type would be rendered at 1200+dpi and the CMYK randoms would be pasted up.

See ( https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5902465 )

Answer (score 0):

`File` → `Export To` → `Images` should do what you’re after.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

But I don't think this will isolate the text and images for each slide, making it editable in Photoshop. Having a series of images is just the beginning — someone will have to essentially recreate each one as a Layered Photoshop file.

Perhaps one solution is to export to a transparent background, so they can at least cut the elements as raster and move them around as needed.

Comment: Was this meant to be a comment to Marc’s answer? The first sentence in your answer doesn’t make much sense as a standalone answer…

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no good way to do this. The issue is that Keynote (much like Powerpoint) is software that's designed to create slideshow presentations for SCREEN use only. People do print out their Powerpoint/Keynote slides for reference material, but in that case the quality of the images/fonts is not crucial.

Just converting a keynote file to a PSD (which isn't really possible; Photoshop won't open a native Keynote file) in and of itself wouldn't make your images hi-res, anyway.  What you really need to do is start with a different application that is meant to build hi-res graphic elements from the beginning. Adobe Illustrator and/or Photoshop are the best options; Adobe InDesign would work to a lesser degree, but it's still a fairly powerful tool.

As you'll find in many other articles on this site, it's not totally impossible to take a lo-res (screen resolution/72 dpi) image and enlarge it to hi-res, but it's not really recommended, especially if you're not well-versed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The key words in your question are “mocked up.”

> I mocked up several marketing materials for my team in Keynote, and
>   I'd like to convert them into high res files

Mockups don’t get “converted” by a machine into publish-ready artwork, they are used as a reference by a human to create publish-ready artwork *from scratch* in a graphics tool.

So the process of creating your publish-ready artwork is like this:

1. create a graphics document (ideally vectors unless there is a
   specific reason not to use vectors) that fits the specification
   (output color mode, dimensions, etc.) just like with any graphics
   project
2. create a layer in the graphics document right above the background
   layer and name it “mockup”
3. import/place the mockup PDF or PNG onto the “mockup” layer, resize
   it to fill the entire canvas, and lock the “mockup” layer
4. create new layers and objects above the “mockup” layer that mimic
   the mockup design
5. hide the “mockup” layer
6. refine the overall design paying attention to details like kerning
   and color palette and so on (graphics it up)
7. export a draft for review by all the principles
8. after approval of the draft, export the publish-ready artwork
9. publish!

This kind of process is followed again and again and again all over the world, all day long, with mockups that were created in Keynote/PowerPoint, MS Paint, any other app, or even drawn on napkins with a Sharpie. The joy of mockups is the freedom to not care about specifications and formats and the golden ratio and so on. You just strap on your goggles and ride your creative motorcycle down a windy road as fast as you can. The pain of mockups is you haven’t really made anything yet. It’s just a map. The actual artwork is a separate journey.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method. It requires MS Powerpoint or MS Excel.

1. Select all on the slide.
2. Group them.
3. Lock aspect ratio and stretch it a lot. *Images will expand in equal proportions.*
4. Select individual text box and change its size. (Ungroup if you want) *It's proportionate so all text boxes of the same size will now be in same range.*
5. Select all and Copy all.
6. Paste in MS Excel.
7. Right click - Save as image.

Only problem is if your images can't tolerate the stretching.